# Поместить строку в поле для ввода текста используя selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Помогите, пожалуйста. Пытаюсь поместить строку в поле для ввода текста письма. 
Где у меня ошибка. Посмотрите последние две строки... 
Код пишу на python 3.4 и selenium 2.46.0

Вот код:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://mail.ru/')
browser.find_element_by_name('Login').clear()
browser.find_element_by_name('Login').send_keys('selenium90')
browser.find_element_by_name('Password').clear()
browser.find_element_by_name('Password').send_keys('pythonrocks')
browser.find_element_by_id('mailbox__auth__button').click()
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('a.b-toolbar__btn').click()
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('textarea.js-input:nth-child(5)').send_keys('07ufo@mail.ru')

browser.switch_to_frame(browser.find_element_by_id('compose_462_composeEditor_ifr'))
browser.find_element_by_class_name('mceContentBody').send_keys('Hello, world!')
```

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to
>   locate element:
>   {"method":"id","selector":"compose_462_composeEditor_ifr"}

Comment: Здесь две проблемы.  Во-первых, поле ввода текста на mail.ru находится внутри iframe.  Нужно переключить фокус в селениум на эту iframe - используя `webdriver.switchTo().frame(...)`.  Вторая проблема в том, что 462 в Вашем id - каждый раз разное число.  Я несколько раз попробовал написать письмо на mail.ru -  и каждый раз получал разные числа с этом id.  Так что Вам придется полагаться на какой-нибудь другой способ.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый коммент, Aleks G, буду искать какой-нибудь другой способ

Answer (score 2):

Если Id не статический, то можно заменить на cssSelector:

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('iframe[id*="compose"]')
```